# Drag and drop: область перетаскивания

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть код js, с помощью которого можно перемещать элементы, но вот никак не пойму, как ограничить область перемещения элемента, например, в пределах конкретного блока?
Скажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать на чистом javascript.

Comment: Вот спецификация dnd для html5 http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/dnd.html#dnd.

Answer (score 5):

```js
Element.prototype.makeDraggable=function(){
  var o=this
  o.onmousedown=function(e){
    var offsetX=e.pageX-parseInt(o.style.left)
    var offsetY=e.pageY-parseInt(o.style.top)
    document.onmousemove=function(e) {
      o.style.left=Math.max(Math.min(e.pageX-offsetX,o.parentNode.clientWidth-o.clientWidth),0)+'px'
      o.style.top=Math.max(Math.min(e.pageY-offsetY,o.parentNode.clientHeight-o.clientHeight),0)+'px'
    }
    document.onmouseup = function(e) {
      document.onmousemove=o.onmouseup=null
    }
  }
  o.ondragstart = function(){return 0}
}
document.getElementById('object1').makeDraggable()
```

```css
#parent{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  background:yellow;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
#object1{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="object1" style="left:10px;top:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете jQuery UI drag and drop, то вот вам такой [пример](http://professorweb.ru/my/javascript/jquery/level4/files/test17.html) из этого [мануала](http://professorweb.ru/my/javascript/jquery/level4/4_12.php).

За привязку к определённому контейнеру отвечает опция с значением:

```
 containment: parent
```

Comment: Я не использую JQuery!!! Хотелось бы на чистом js понять, как работает ограничение.

Comment: Крутой какой :) какой способ D&D вы используете? HTML5? Или просто что-то самописное с mousedown и т.д.? В  любом случае - когда элемент вне зоны, в которой можно таскать, просто не обновляйте его координаты.

Comment: был бы крутой, не задавал такие вопросы! Такой код у меня http://jsfiddle.net/acchtbcb/ но что то на jsfiddle не работает, в браузере все нормально. А может знаешь, плагины типа jquery draggable используют тот же принцип, по достижению определенного места, координаты перестаю обновляться?

Comment: @sew810i9, и в чем проблема? Вы же знаете, когда у вас двигается элемент, границы того, что двигается, и границы поля. В чем проблема? Вот демо http://jsfiddle.net/acchtbcb/1/ чтобы работало на jsfiddle

Comment: А вообще, у вас там все неправильно :)

Comment: А можно узнать, как правильно?

Comment: правильно не вешать обработчики событий все время, а повесить их один раз, а поведение менять флагами или просто состоянием системы, кроме того можно использовать .addEventListener() или его аналог для старых браузеров (а лучше shim),